# Does iterator continuously provide current view of the underlying data in LevelDB?

Tags: java, leveldb

I am trying to use the same iterator over a period of time in leveldb. Once I create an iterator, if there are changes from another thread, will leveldb iterator provide those changes? Or do I have to create an another iterator?

Comment: +1 I would assume it is not a live or continuous query unless the product system so.

Comment: in my experience LevelDB is good at reflecting recent changes even when they have not yet been committed to disk. BUT when we're talking about threads we're talking about a can of worms, as it is, in the general case, hard or impossible to tell exactly *when* two threads execute. this is not a LevelDB issue, it's an issue with threads. Closer to your question, when you create an iterator, it will certainly not read in the entire DB and keep acting on the state at that point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existing leveldb iterator will **not** reflect those changes. An iterator operates on a snapshot of the database taken when the iterator is created.

This came up in a recent thread to the leveldb mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leveldb/nT2BZ6gKAEc